# Solve max height of up to 20 objects

Tags: javascript

I have 1 to 20 objects inside a canvas.
The objects have left, width, top and height attributes.

I divided my canvas into 12 sections. Each objects width can be 1/12th of the canvas width (month) or 3/12th (quarter).

Now I need to get the sum of the heights of all objects inside each of the 12 grid sections.

For example.
In section 1 is 1 month-object with the height 12 --> result 12
In section 2 are 2 month-objects. heights 10 and 14 --> result 24
In section 4 are 1 month-object and one quarter object: heights 12 and 14 -->result 26
In section 5 are 1 month-object and the same quarter object: heights 4 and 14 --> result 18

Hope this was understandable. Solution is needed in javascript.
What I have is an array with all the beginning sections and all the ending sections.

For example:

```
startingSections = [1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5]
endingSections = [1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5]
```

My desired output is the following:

```
var sectionsMax = [];
sectiosnMax = getMonthlyTops();

function getMonthlyTops(){
  var monthlyTops = [];

  /* Code here */

  return monthlyTops;
}
```

Results could be:

```
sectionsMax = [12, 24, 0, 26, 18, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Example picture:
[image: Example]

Comment: Can you put an image of your desired canvas for a better understanding with some simple example like `startingSections = [1, 2, 2]; endingSections = [1, 2, 2];`

Comment: As you can see in the picture. there are 6 objects. Each have their height, top, left and width attributes which describe their position and their dimensions in the layer.
now object 1 starts in section 1 and ends in section 1.
Thus: its the first 1 in startingSections and the first item in endingSections (1). and so on for the other objects.

Comment: Wait a second. Those objects are already inside that canvas. You dont want any calculations to paint the canvas, you just want to loop through the objects which are already there, get their heights and show the sums. Am i right?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I need the sums for each section. This is how I can access each object: `canvas.forEachObject(function (targ) { /*code here e.g. targ.left, targ.width */ });`

Comment: Are you sections indexed from 1 to n or from 0 to n-1 ?

Comment: They are indexed from 1 to n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and post what you get please. Since you can loop through the objects, i dont think you actually need `startingSections` and `endingSections` arrays.

```
var monthlyTops = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
canvas.forEachObject(function (targ) {
  x = targ.left / (canvas.width / 12);
  for (i = x; i < (x + targ.width / (canvas.width / 12) ); i++)
    monthlyTops[i] += targ.height;
});
return monthlyTops;
```

Comment: it works like a charm. Thank you! Could you comment what youre actually doing please? And you need to change target to targ.
I will post a picture of the output.

Comment: my console output for the above picture example is '[124, 100, 0, 310, 188, 151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9999999999999999: NaN]' why do I get the NaN error? The other values are correct, since they are actual values of the canvas.

Comment: For the Nan error : i think your loop is being executed 13 times. What is the height of your canvas?

Comment: I'd recommend to cache the boundary computation `for (var i = x, boundary = (x + targ.width / (canvas.width / 12))|0; i < boundary; i++)`